# How do different filesystems handle reads concurrent with read-write/update access?

Tags: file-io, shutil, nas

[Concurrent Read/Write](https://I%20need%20to%20find%20someone%20in%20the%20company%20who%20would%20understand%20the%20internals%20of%20network%20access%20storage%20units.%C2%A0Specifically,%20what%20happens%20when%20we%20copy%20a%20file%20from%20a%20NAS%20unit-%20can%20any%20other%20process%20using%20that%20file,%20say%20on%20another%20machine%20be%20affected%20by%20a%20concurrent%20read?%20We%20have%20a%20system%20that%20uses%20NAS%20for%20storing%20several%20Microsoft%20access%20databases%20which%20are%20known%20to%20have%20issues%20with%20concurrent%20***modifications***:%C2%A0forms%20-%20MS%20Access%20DB%20Instance%20getting%20corrupted%20when%20put%20on%20shared%20server%20-%20Super%20UserBut%20not%20open%20connections%20necessary:%C2%A0connection%20-%20MS%20Access%20back-end%20database%20corruption%20-%20Stack%20OverflowHere%20is%20one%20collection%20of%20ways%20Access%20files%20can%20break.%C2%A0Top%2010%20Microsoft%20Access%20Database%20Corruption%20Causes%20(stellarinfo.com)In%20any%20case,%20all%20those%20failures%20are%20through%20opening%20the%20access%20database%20with%20windows%20drivers%20and%20the%20like.%20No%20information%20seems%20to%20be%20available%20online%20concerning%20base%20filesystem%20acess%20to%20the%20.db%20file.I%20maintain%20that%20concurrent%20filesystem%20reads%20(a%20call%20to%20copy%20the%20files%20from%20one%20directory%20to%20another%20from%20a%20different%20machine%20that%20also%20has%20access%20to%20the%20NAS%20unit)%20should%20not%20have%20any%20influence%20on%20other%20processes%20that%20are%20on%20different%20machines,%20but%20this%20is%20not%20my%20expertise.%C2%A0I%20can%20test%20this%20pretty%20easily%20on%20say%20a%20folder%20in%20the%20F%20drive%20using%20two%20machines,%20but%20the%20F%20drive%20is%20a%20bit%20more%20advanced,%20having%20limited%20version%20control%20and%20file%20locking%20capabilities%20not%20available%20on%20the%20NAS%20unit.)

For any given NAS architecture, if user B wants to copy the file from the NAS device and User B (using a different machine to access the NAS):

1. Is already modifying the file when user A copies it
2. Tries to start modifying the file while user A copies it

I have seen on Machine B that a copy does not create a lock. How will these be handled?
With file-types such as .acdb, known to have concurrent access issues when opened, can copying avoid file corruption?

Copy means specifically python's shutil module's `shutil.copy(source_path,destination_path)` method.